# SQL joins vs subqueries vs exists for matching and filtering rows

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which has the following fields : `Id, Name, Dept`

Sample data :

```
ID    Name    Dept 
1     John      A   
2     Mary      A   
3     Tom       A   
4     David     A   
5     Mary      B   
6     David     B
```

I am trying to get the names which are in Dept`'A'` but NOT in Dept`'B'`

I was able to come up with a query which gives the desired results :

```
select Id, Name, Dept
from test
Where  Dept= 'a' and name not in (
  select name from test where Dept= 'b')
```

But how can I do the same with joins?

Comment: `SELECT a.Id, a.Name, a.Dept
FROM test a
 LEFT OUTER JOIN test b
 ON a.Name = b.Name
WHERE a.Dept = 'a' 
 AND b.Dept = 'b'
 AND b.Name IS NULL` I think an optimizer does much better with the `NOT IN` Syntax though as it can use an `ANTI JOIN` (at least in SQL Server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2
    ON t1.Name = t2.Name
    AND t2.Dept = 'B'
WHERE
    t1.Dept = 'A'
    AND t2.ID IS NULL
```

But I prefer the `NOT EXISTS` approach:

```
SELECT *
FROM test t
WHERE
    t.Dept = 'A'
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE Name = t.Name AND Dept = 'B')
```

Aaron Bertrand wrote an article comparing the different techniques to check for existence of a row, with `NOT EXISTS` typically being the best choice.

- [Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Comment: I am confused about the filter i.e "t2.id is null" could you pls explain

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT A.Id, A.Name, A.Dept
FROM test A, test B
WHERE A.Dept= 'a' 
AND B.Dept = 'b'
AND A.Name <> B.Name
```

Comment: [Please avoid using old-style `JOIN` syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: Why?  Was that part of the parameters here?  That syntax is valid.

Comment: I didn't say it was invalid. Have you checked the article linked in my comment?

Comment: Well, I can't say that I agree that long verbose syntax is superior.  This is pretty clean and understandable I think, even it has fallen out of fashion, or "is not as easy to comment out parts of it"...